# C# - Group Objects by Property Value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a console app written in C#. In my app, I have an object defined like this:

```
public class Order
{
  public double Price { get; set; }

  public string Description { get; set; }

  public int ItemCount { get; set; }
}
```

I have the `Order` objects in a `List<Order>`. I need to group these Orders by their Price. But, the groups represent a price range. For example, I want the following groups:

```
$0 - $10
$10 - $20
$20 - $30
$30 - $40
$40 - $50
$50 - $60
$60 - $70
$70 - $80
$80 - $90
$90 - $100
```

Originally, I was going to just loop through the `List<Order>`, but it seemed clunky. I felt this was a good case for Linq, but I've come up short. My approach isn't working.

Is there a way to group the orders into $10 increments based on the `Price` property with LINQ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828216/group-by-range-using-linq

Comment: What about giving the class a `GetGroup()` method and group by that value? If the grouping logic can be defined by class, that is.

Comment: Group ranges are incorrect as they overlap, where does $10 comes in  0-10 or 10-20, you need to create exclusive ranges

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work : `var groups = orders.GroupBy(order => order.Price - order.Price % 10);`

Comment: Due to the idiosyncrasies of how doubles work and the fact that a `GroupBy` does a `.Equals(` comparison to make its groups I would be careful of this answer. When dealing with larger numbers you may end up with groups with a fraction of a cent assigned to them.

Comment: Meh, I ran some tests, I could not get it to fail on any number between `0` and `Int32.MaxValue`. I also tried `Int64.MaxValue`, `Int64.MaxValue-1`, `Double.MaxValue`, and `Double.MaxValue - 1.2` and those did not fail either. I think for most reasonable uses this method is fine to do.

Comment: Why does $10 belongs to 0-10 not 10-20 ?

Answer (score 4):

Use integer arithmetic and GroupBy, for example:

`orders.GroupBy(o => (int)o.Price / 10)`

Comment: C# has a `%` modulo operator.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin so? I don't see how the modulo operator would be useful here.

Comment: Nevermind, [Toto's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43353494/80274) showed how you could use it.